# Inheritance issue with Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have four classes:
`Application, CaperData, ApplicationDTO, CaperDataDTO`

`Application` is inheritting from `CaperData` as follows:

```
public class Application : CaperData
```

And in `ApplicationDTO`, we have a property of type `CaperDataDTO`.

`CaperData` and `CaperDataDTO` are identical on the properties level.

`Application` and `ApplicationDTO` are also identical with 1 difference that the first one extends from `CaperData` but the second one does not extend from `CaperDataDTO`, instead, it has the property `CaperDataDTO` inside of it.

I need to map all the clases together in `autoMapper`

Application with `ApplicationDTO` and vice versa

`CaperData` with `CaperDataDTO` and vice versa

```
using AutoMapper;

public class Application : CaperData
{
    // Properties and methods specific to Application
}

public class CaperData
{
    // Properties and methods specific to CaperData
}

public class ApplicationDTO
{
    public CaperDataDTO CopData { get; set; }
    // Other properties and methods specific to ApplicationDTO
}

public class CaperDataDTO
{
    // Properties and methods specific to CaperDataDTO
}
```

How can I do the mapping configuration in MappingProfile?

What I tried so far is:

```
CreateMap<CaperData, CaperDataDTO>();
CreateMap<CaperDataDTO, CaperData>();

CreateMap<Application, ApplicationDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CapData, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));


CreateMap<ApplicationDTO, Application>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AppName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CapData.AppName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ErrorMessage, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CapData.ErrorMessage))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Reason, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CapData.Reason));
```

When I try to map, as follows:

```
List<Application> apps = _appRepo.GetData();
var mappedApps = _mapper.Map<ApplicationDTO>(apps );
```

I am receiving the following exception:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
List`1 -> ApplicationDTO
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[DAL.Model.Application, DAL, Version=3.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> Client.Models.ApplicationDTO`
```

Comment: Please provide the complete exception message. It will tell you which class mapping rule is missing. Also, show your code that you are mapping from which class to another class.

Comment: updated my question to include the mapping code and full exception

Comment: You are mapping from a list to single item. I believe you want to have multiple items as mappedApp**s**: `var mappedApps = _mapper.Map<List<ApplicationDTO>>(apps);`

Comment: Yes correct, I was missing that. Thank you that was helpful